# Count multiple columns

Tags: mysql, sql

I have this table:

```
Teams:
ID | Size1 | Size2 | Size3 | Size4 | ... (other columns)..
----------------------------------------
1  |  L    |  XL   |   L   |   M   | ...
----------------------------------------
2  |  S    |  L    |   S   |  XXL  | ...
----------------------------------------
3  |  M    |  XXL  |   L   |   M   | ...
----------------------------------------
4  |  L    |  XL   |  XS   |  XXL  | ...
```

What is the most effective (and simplest) MySQL query to count all **L** in table?

I'd like to have only one field in result which is the count of all **L** in all columns.

EDIT:
Just to clarify little more, in my table there is 152 Ls in first column, 2 in second, 151 in third and 3 in fourth and I expect 308 as result

Comment: `SELECT (
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Teams 
WHERE Size1='L'
) + 
(
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Teams 
WHERE Size2='L'
)
+
(
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Teams 
WHERE Size3='L'
)
+
(
SELECT COUNT(*) 
FROM Teams 
WHERE Size4='L'
)
+
(
...
);`

Comment: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_func_count.asp

Comment: consider normalizing size fields to their own table - then only have to do single count on that - and not have to change table if you have another size. Otherwise Alexander's answer is the way to go.

Comment: @Buksy now you need to check all queries on perfomance, and give the final answer

Comment: And, btw, if this is the table that shows availability of the clothes of each size, this architecture isn't the best one.

Comment: yes, architecture isnt best, but its working system I got to maintain and I can't afford to change it because lot of scripts rely on it :/ ... I will make performence tests later :)

Answer (score 4):

You can use `SUM` and `CASE` to do that:

```
SELECT 
  sum(case when Size1 = 'L' then 1 else 0 end) +
  sum(case when Size2 = 'L'  then 1 else 0 end) +
  sum(case when Size3 = 'L'  then 1 else 0 end) +
  sum(case when Size4 = 'L'  then 1 else 0 end)
FROM Teams;
```

Alternatively instead of `CASE`, you can use `IF`:

```
SELECT 
  sum(IF(Size1 = 'L',1, 0)) +
  sum(IF(Size2 = 'L',1, 0)) +
  sum(IF(Size3 = 'L',1, 0)) +
  sum(IF(Size4 = 'L',1, 0))
FROM Teams;
```

This is actually the same.

**Edit.**

According to Andomar's comment there's even simpler solution:

```
SELECT 
  sum(Size1 = 'L') +
  sum(Size2 = 'L') +
  sum(Size3 = 'L') +
  sum(Size4 = 'L')
FROM Teams;
```

This is correct since `true` is equal to `1` in MySQL. I've just verified this. ;-)

**2nd Edit**

Next step to simplify this - only one `SUM` usage:

```
   SELECT sum(
      (Size1 = 'L') + 
      (Size2 = 'L') +
      (Size3 = 'L') +
      (Size4 = 'L') )
    FROM Teams;
```

Comment: Since in MySQL true is 1, a shorter version would be `sum(size = 'L')`.  Example at [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2ed84/1/0).

Comment: you have typo in parentheses in second Query, I cant edit it :)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming there can only be one `'L'` per row:

```
select  count(*)
from    YourTable
where   'L' in (Size1, Size2, ..., SizeN)
```

Or a normalizing solution, which supports multiple `'L'`'s per row:

```
select  count(*)
from    (
        select  size1 as size
        from    YourTable
        union all 
        select  size2
        from    YourTable
        union all 
        select  size3
        from    YourTable
        union all 
        ...
        )
where   size = 'L'
```

Comment: Can you do value in column like that? That's news to me

Comment: @Askanison4: `a in (b,c,d)` is just syntactic sugar for `a = b or a = c or a = d`

Comment: @dragoste: Correct.  I assumed it wouldn't make sense to have two sizes called `L` for the same product, and the example data agrees with that.

Comment: @Andomar we're not here to decide what makes sense in authors task. There are two `L`s in first row in provided example data.

Comment: The first query doesnt work to me `SELECT count( * )
FROM table WHERE 'L' IN (size1, size2, size3, size4)` returns 152, while there is 152 Ls in first column, 2 in second, 151 in third and 3 in fourth

Comment: @Buksy Try out my solution below - It's simpler and will count the columns and total based on content so that there are no issues with L being in a row twice

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following query:

```
SELECT sum( 
  IF(Size1='L', 1, 0) + 
  IF(Size2='L', 1, 0) + 
  IF(Size3='L', 1, 0) + 
  IF(Size4='L', 1, 0)
) as total FROM Teams
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `WHERE` condition is going to be quite large but you could use this:

`SELECT count(Size1) + count(size2) AS total WHERE size1 = 'L' OR size2 = 'L'`

This solution will count all columns and total based on individual column comparisons.

Comment: This should count rows twice even if there is only one L

Comment: @Andomar Yes this is his expected result.